# Use ADDRESS function to define range in MIN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a newby to this forum.  I have a spreadsheet which predicts bank balance based on future events.  I want to know the minimum balance in the future, to ensure I don't overspend.

I can find the minimum in the account over whole range of dates by using `MIN`, but this includes past dates. I want to vary the range in the `MIN` argument based on the `TODAY` function.

I can return the cell reference I need to use for today's date using `=ADDRESS(MATCH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"dd mmm yy")),C:C,0),COLUMN(E2),4)`, where Column `C` contains dates, and Column `E` the bank balance.  However, I cannot then use the value of the cell in the `MIN` formula.

So, at present, `MIN(E10-E121)` works for past and future levels, but if the `ADDRESS` routine for todays date returns `E90` in cell `A1`, I cannot reference `A1` within the `MIN` function to get the range `E90:E121`.

I have tried `INDIRECT`, but this gives the value of the cell at `E90`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in rows 2 to 100, this will give you the smallest amount anywhere in column E where the date in column C is today or later. It's an [array formula](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx), so must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MIN(IF(C2:C100>=TODAY(),E2:E100))
```

EDIT:

In response to your comment about how to do it using one cell in a range, this uses `Match` to find the last cell in column C that is less than or equal to `Today()` and then uses that as the `Index` into the first half of a range specification in column E. It requires the column be sorted, ascending, by date, and if today isn't in column C it will start with the highest row in column C with a date before today. You could fiddle with the last argument in `Match` - 1, 0, or -1, but if C always contains today's date this will work:

```
=MIN(INDEX(E2:E100,MATCH(TODAY(),C2:C100,1)):E100)
```

Comment: Many thanks - that works a treat!  A far more elegant solution to boot.  Out of interest (having spent some time looking for a solution on the web), is there a way to use the content of one cell in a range as I was originally trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that does not involve array formulas (but with a little more involved formula):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MIN((C2:C100<TODAY())*(1+MAX(E2:E100))+(E2:E100)*(C2:C100>=TODAY())))
```